# Check time every minute by broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-alarms

I want to check the time every minute to make alarm app but when I but this in receiver

```
<action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"/>
```

and put this in broadcast receiver

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,"changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    }
```

My app don't work or do any thing 
I searched more and more but nothing was useful I hope someone help me

Comment: have you register your receiver

Answer (score 1):

From the way you wrote `<action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED"/>`, it appears that you're trying to register your `BroadcastReceiver` in the `Manifest.xml`.

However, I'll quote this straight from the documentation:

> ACTION_TIME_TICK
>
> Broadcast Action: The current time has changed. Sent every minute. You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().
>
> --https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK

You can only receive this broadcast by registering the `BroadcastReceiver` through the `registerReceiver()` method in either something like your `Activity` or `Service`.

However, I do want to mention that you should **avoid** using this broadcast if your intention is to create an Alarm app.

Constantly fetching the time every minute can become quite battery draining, especially if the alarm takes a while to ring.

Instead, you should consider scheduling your alarm through services like `JobScheduler` or `AlarmManager`.